# VBA filtering a column with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to filter a column between values but those values are variables within my spreadsheet. Whenever I use this it filters all of the values and nothing is displayed. I'm assuming it's something with the syntax between the ">=" and "<=" in combination with the variables upper_limit and lower_limit but I can't quite figure it out.

```
Sub Filter_QB_Cost()
'
' Filter_QB_Cost Macro
'
    Dim upper_limit As Integer
    Dim lower_limit As Integer
    
    upper_limit = Application.Workbooks("Fantasy FB.xlsm").Worksheets("QB Selection").Range("D6")
    lower_limit = Application.Workbooks("Fantasy FB.xlsm").Worksheets("QB Selection").Range("D7")
'

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table11").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        ">=lower_limit", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=upper_limit"
End Sub
```

Comment: `">="&lower_limit` note the use and location of the ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test it but you're missing some quotes and ampersands in order for the variables to be read.

Also some minor fixes with variable types and extra qualifiers not needed.

```
Sub Filter_QB_Cost()
'
' Filter_QB_Cost Macro
'
    Dim upper_limit As Long
    Dim lower_limit As Long
    
    upper_limit = Workbooks("Fantasy FB.xlsm").Worksheets("QB Selection").Range("D6").Value
    lower_limit = Workbooks("Fantasy FB.xlsm").Worksheets("QB Selection").Range("D7").Value
'

    ListObjects("Table11").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & lower_limit & "", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & upper_limit
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&` operator to concatenate strings and variables:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table11").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        ">="&lower_limit&"", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<="&upper_limit
```